# Running deeplearning4j intellij program from command line interface

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line-interface, deeplearning4j

i want to run my deeplearning4j program that i created as IntelliJ project from server with command line input and i don't have any clue how to do it, any suggestion?

Comment: Find a main class and run it.  How can you understand deep learning if you can't run Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our examples you'll see the maven-shade-plugin:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/pom.xml

Use this as a base.
That creates an uber jar already. Just use java -cp on the uber jar and you're set.